# Apache Spark - Simple Word Count gets: SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

i'm trying to do some tests on Apache Spark (v1.3.0), i have a simple Java 8 class:

```
public class WordCount {
    private JavaSparkContext ctx;
    private String inputFile, outputFile;
    public WordCount(String inputFile, String outputFile) {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
        this.outputFile = outputFile;
        // Initialize Spark Conf
        ctx = new JavaSparkContext("local", "WordCount",
                System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), System.getenv("JARS"));

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String inputFile = "/home/workspace/spark/src/main/resources/inferno.txt";//args[0];
        String outputFile = "/home/workspace/spark/src/main/resources/dv";//args[1];
        WordCount wc = new WordCount(inputFile, outputFile);
        wc.doWordCount();
        wc.close();
    }

    public void doWordCount() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        JavaRDD<String> inputRdd = ctx.textFile(inputFile);
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> count = inputRdd.flatMapToPair((String s) -> {
            List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).forEach(s1 -> list.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s1, 1)));
            return list;
        }).reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y);
        List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> list = count.takeOrdered(10, 
                (o1, o2) -> o2._2() - o1._2());
        list.forEach(t2 -> System.out.println(t2._1()));
//      count.saveAsTextFile(outputFile);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(String.format("Time in ms is: %d", end - start));
    }

    public void close() {
        ctx.stop();
    }

}
```

When i run it get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1622)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.takeOrdered(RDD.scala:1231)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.takeOrdered(JavaRDDLike.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.takeOrdered(JavaPairRDD.scala:45)
    at it.conker.spark.base.WordCount.doWordCount2(WordCount.java:65)
    at it.conker.spark.base.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: it.conker.spark.base.WordCount$$Lambda$10/1541232265
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: it.conker.spark.base.WordCount$$Lambda$10/1541232265, value: it.conker.spark.base.WordCount$$Lambda$10/1541232265@213860b8)
    - field (class: scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$7, name: cmp$2, type: interface java.util.Comparator)
    - object (class scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$7, scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$7@511505e7)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$34, name: ord$1, type: interface scala.math.Ordering)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$34, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14, name: f$3, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14, <function3>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
    ... 8 more
```

This is mi pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <groupId>it.conker.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>learning-spark-by-example</artifactId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>Learning Spark by example</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

I run the class within eclipse.
Can someone tell me where i was wrong?

**Edit:**
As mark91 ask, replacing the the line:

```
List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> list = count.takeOrdered(10, 
            (o1, o2) -> o2._2() - o1._2());
```

with:

```
List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> list = count.takeOrdered(10);
```

I have got this exception:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at org.spark-project.guava.collect.NaturalOrdering.compare(NaturalOrdering.java:28)
    at scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$7.compare(Ordering.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$$anon$1.compare(Utils.scala:35)
    at org.spark-project.guava.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:672)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$34.apply(RDD.scala:1234)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$34.apply(RDD.scala:1231)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/03/27 17:58:55 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at org.spark-project.guava.collect.NaturalOrdering.compare(NaturalOrdering.java:28)
    at scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$7.compare(Ordering.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$$anon$1.compare(Utils.scala:35)
    at org.spark-project.guava.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:672)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$34.apply(RDD.scala:1234)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$34.apply(RDD.scala:1231)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15/03/27 17:58:55 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/03/27 17:58:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/03/27 17:58:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 1
15/03/27 17:58:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: takeOrdered at WordCount.java:66, took 14.117721 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at org.spark-project.guava.collect.NaturalOrdering.compare(NaturalOrdering.java:28)
    at scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$7.compare(Ordering.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$$anon$1.compare(Utils.scala:35)
    at org.spark-project.guava.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:672)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$34.apply(RDD.scala:1234)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$34.apply(RDD.scala:1231)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove your lambda function passed as second parameter to your takeOrdered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the reason is that all classes you use in your precessing (i.e. objects stored in your RDD and classes which are Functions to be passed to spark) need to be `Serializable`. This means that they need to implement the `Serializable` interface or you have to provide another way to serialize them as Kryo. Actually I don't know why the lambda function you are defining is not considered serializable, but I believe that this is due to the fact that a Java `Comparator` takes a parameter.

However, the way to make it working is defining a `Serializable` comaprator such as :

```
public class WordCountComparator implements Comparator<Tuple2<String, Integer>>, Serializable {

@Override
public int compare(Tuple2<String, Integer> o1, Tuple2<String, Integer> o2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return o2._2()-o1._2();
}



}
```

and then passing an instance of it to your `takeOrdered` function as second parameter.

Comment: Wow it works. You think is it a Spark bug? Maybe i can open an issue in their github

Comment: No I don't think so, but I do not know why it behaves like this... I guess the reason is for the parameter you have to pass to the `Comparator` interface but I am not sure.

Comment: Try this. As @mark91 mentioned the function you pass should be serialized. you can make your lambda serialized by mentioning it explicitly. List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> list = count.takeOrdered(10, 
              (Comparator & Serializable)  (o1, o2) -> o2._2() - o1._2());